# How can I fix Fortnite iOS stuttering/freezing/lag?

Tags: ios, fortnite-battle-royale

Sometimes when I play Fortnite on my iPhone X the framerate will get really low, sometimes to the point where it will freeze for a few seconds between frames. Any ideas how to resolve? It didn't do this when I first played.

Comment: How long do you play on your phone? And after what duration of time does this start happening? Phones have very bad cooling, so if your phone is heating up, you phone will "overheat" and under-clock the CPU, which can result in frame rate loss

Comment: Sometimes it will happen on the first round I play on a day. As I wrote in an answer, restarting the phone seems to help, but would be nice to find a permanent solution.

Comment: Might also be a power management issue where the phone doesn't correctly estimate how much computational power is required and underclocks the phone to preserve battery. Maybe connecting a charger or power bank helps? Also check internet connectivity to rule out network lag.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've found that can greatly improve the situation is if I restart my phone. Maybe having lots of apps running in the background could lead to this freezing?

Answer (score 0):

Thermal throttling is what your phone does when it gets hot playing games.
Keeps your phone cool but slows down your game. Obviously closing out of running apps would help.

I'm not sure what you expected when you're playing an online 3D fps game on your phone.

It's not a gaming computer, it's a flappy bird machine.

Of course you can always do what Linus does and watercool your phone to prevent thermal throttling but **watercooling your phone is not recommended.**

You could also take breaks playing the game so your phone doesn't heat up or keep a cold pack near by.